# When is system scheduled for reboot?

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot

Where can I find information about if there is an reboot scheduled and in that case: when, why and by who?

---

I got this in my terminal:

```
Broadcast message from root@my-server (Tue 2017-11-07 09:00:00 CET):

The system is going down for reboot at Wed 2017-11-08 02:00:00 CET!
```

So in a couple of hours the system will be rebooted, that's good. But after working for a while and the message is scrolled out of visibility or if the terminal is closed:

**How can I get hold of the reboot time?**

If I again login to the server I only get the message:

```
*** System restart required ***
```

There is no information about the upcoming reboot. I have tried to see if there is any shutdown processes running, but could not find any.

I know I could produce a similar message by issuing a command like this:

```
sudo shutdown -r 02:00
```

So, how do I find information about any upcoming reboots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an Ubuntu 18.04 machine shutdown is managed by `systemd`. On my machine I have enabled automatic reboots via unattended upgrades:

```
$ grep Automatic-Reboot /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

The scheduled automatic reboot time is stored in `/run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`.

```
$ cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled
USEC=1563976800000000 
WARN_WALL=1
MODE=reboot
```

You can convert this to a human readable time using the following command:

```
$ date -d "@$( awk -F '=' '/USEC/{ $2=substr($2,1,10); print $2 }' /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled )"
Thu Jul 25 02:00:00 NZST 2019
```

Answer (score 2):

As started with `sudo shutdown -r 02:00` it's not a file / setting / system variable / crontab entry. The `shutdown` is a process and if it's still pending, you should see it.

```
$ ps -ef | grep shutdown
root      3155  2941  0 12:04 pts/4    00:00:00 sudo shutdown -r 02:00
root      3156  3155  0 12:04 pts/4    00:00:00 shutdown -r 02:00
esa       3158  2937  0 12:04 pts/3    00:00:00 grep shutdown
```

If it's cancelled with external command `sudo shutdown -c` or by pressing `^C` in `pts/4`, the process will show a message `Shutdown cancelled.` and exit. So if it's not there:

- someone has cancelled the shutdown after the message.
- the message was produced with `shutdown -k` (Don't really shutdown; only send the warning messages to everybody. In some versions this also prevents new logins.)
- you are running `ps` with a user account that doesn't see processes of other users.

Comment: Point1, I get a new message every hour. So no, I don't think so. Point2, why would the system fool me like that? Point3, no thats not the case: `sudo ps aux | grep shutdown` gives me no response.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu machines, the 'reboot required' message upon login comes from the file at `/var/run/reboot-required`. This file is removed during the update/reboot process.

The reboot time is set with `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time` in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file.

As Esa stated, the broadcast message was most likely produced by something else executing `shutdown -k`, which only prints the message and exits. I also observe the broadcast messages, but afterwards, `sudo ps faux` shows me no `shutdown` processes that are running.

It's worth noting that even though no `shutdown` process stays running, something does seem to keep track of when the original shutdown time was scheduled. Even when I change the value for reboot time, subsequent broadcast messages still show me the originally configured time.